# a general order was too big a lick

Tags: expressions

I'd like to learn what "too big a lick" means in the following.

> Thus to Sumner, who called at the White House twice on July 4 "to urge the reconsecration of the day by a decree of emancipation," the President said that a general order was "too big a lick," though Sumner believed he was not "disinclined" to issue a proclamation covering eastern Virginia.

Source: *Lincoln* by David Herbert Donald, p. 364

Answer (score 1):

Subject: the early negotiations of the Emancipation Proclamation

Lincoln and **"too big a lick"**  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=2UuNCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT94&ots=HNAR--wTOR&dq=Lincoln%20replied%20that%20it%20would%20be%20%22too%20big%20a%20lick.%22&pg=PT94#v=onepage&q=Lincoln%20replied%20that%20it%20would%20be%20%22too%20big%20a%20lick.%22&f=false)

> Lincoln was concerned that a full and immediate proclamation would
>   result in half the Union troops deserting in protest and losing some
>   of the wavering border states.

In this example it was too much ... too soon to take a lick at.

Answer (score 0):

From *The Language of the Civil War* by John D. Wright, p. 176

**lick** 1. A physical hit or mental blow. When Senator Charles Sumner of Massachusetts asked President Abraham Lincoln to issue a general a decree of emancipation on July 4, 1862, Lincoln replied that it would be "too big a lick." 2. A tiny amount or small portion or a bit. This Scottish word was used then and now in such sentences as,"He can't fight a lick."

Answer (score -1):

*A task that is too difficult take on*

or

*A task doomed to fail*

Sounds like southern slang, not sure.
Less likely, but could mean *overkill*.

Comment: Thank you. I think I should take this : A task that is too difficult take on

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please add references to improve your answer.